# How to simplify a logical expression with several FiniteSets

Tags: python, logic, sympy, logical-operators

Using the Python package `sympy` (version 1.12) I have several `FiniteSet`s and an expression I want to simplify/optimize.

As an example says more than thousand words:

```py
from sympy import Symbol, FiniteSet, simplify_logic, Contains

a = Symbol("a")
x = FiniteSet("1", "2")
y = FiniteSet("2", "3")
z = FiniteSet("3", "4")

>>> simplify_logic(Contains(a, x) & Contains(a, z))
Returned: Contains(a, {1, 2}) & Contains(a, {3, 4})
Expected: False

>>> simplify_logic(Contains(a, x) & Contains(a, y))
Returned: Contains(a, {1, 2}) & Contains(a, {2, 3})
Expected: Contains(a, {2})

>>> simplify_logic(Contains(a, x) | Contains(a, y))
Returned: Contains(a, {1, 2}) & Contains(a, {2, 3})
Expected: Contains(a, {1, 2, 3})

>>> simplify_logic(Contains(a, x) | Contains(a, z))
Returned: Contains(a, {1, 2}) | Contains(a, {3, 4})
Expected: Contains(a, {1, 2, 3, 4})
```

For clarity, in case of an additional symbol `b = Symbol("b")`, the following would be expected:

```py
>>> simplify_logic(Contains(a, x) & Contains(b, x))
Returned/Expected: Contains(a, {1, 2}) & Contains(b, {1, 2})

>>> simplify_logic(Contains(a, x) | Contains(b, x))
Returned/Expected: Contains(a, {1, 2}) | Contains(b, {1, 2})
```

It seems that `sympy` does not handle such simplifications (yet).
For my particular use-case, the examples/simplifications given above would already cover my use-cases as my application only uses `FiniteSet`s.

**Question:**
Is there already a way to let `sympy` do the simplifications as shown above directly out of the box? If not, would it be possible (and how) to e.g. extend the `FiniteSet` class to cover such cases?
Or is this not possible/advised as there are any edge-cases I could not think of?

Note: To play around, one needs to use the current master as a recent bug [preventing `Contains` to be simplified at all](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/25115) has been fixed (Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

There are various things that you could try. Firstly note that the `contains` method will simplify the `Contains` to a basic relational and logical expressions if possible:

```
In [36]: Contains(a, x)
Out[36]: a ∈ {1, 2}

In [37]: x.contains(a)
Out[37]: 1 = a ∨ 2 = a
```

You can use this along with further manipulations:

```
In [39]: (x.contains(a) & z.contains(a))
Out[39]: (1 = a ∨ 2 = a) ∧ (3 = a ∨ 4 = a)

In [40]: (x.contains(a) & z.contains(a)).as_set()
Out[40]: ∅

In [41]: Contains(a, (x.contains(a) & z.contains(a)).as_set())
Out[41]: False

In [42]: Contains(a, (x.contains(a) & y.contains(a)).as_set())
Out[42]: a ∈ {2}

In [43]: Contains(a, (x.contains(a) | y.contains(a)).as_set())
Out[43]: a ∈ {1, 2, 3}

In [44]: Contains(a, (x.contains(a) | z.contains(a)).as_set())
Out[44]: a ∈ {1, 2, 3, 4}

In [45]: Contains(a, (x.contains(a) & x.contains(b)).as_set())
```

This approach will only work with a single symbol because `as_set` requires there to be only one. There are other operations that can be tried though like `to_cnf`, `to_dnf` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own routine to simply Contains within And or Or (which can be extracted from a larger expression with `expr.atoms(And, Or)`)>

```py
def simpContains(o):
    assert isinstance(o, (And, Or))
    kv  = {}
    for a in o.args:
        if isinstance(a, Contains) and isinstance(a.args[1], FiniteSet):
            e, s = a.args
            if e not in kv:
                kv[e]=o.func.identity.as_set()
            kv[e] =(kv[e]& s) if isinstance(o, And) else (kv[e]|s)
        else:
            if 'other' not in kv:
                kv['other']=[]
            kv['other'].append(a)
    args = kv.pop('other') if 'other' in kv else []
    for k in kv:
        args.append(Contains(k, kv[k]))
    return o.func(*args)

>>> args = (Contains(a, {1, 2}), Contains(a, {2, 3}))
>>> simpContains(Or(*args))
Contains(a, {1, 2, 3})
>>> simpContains(And(*args))
Contains(a, {2})
```